# Cell content alignment for Static table cell in tableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, storyboard

I have static cells in my `UITableView` with cell style as right detail

Left detail has static content and the right detail shows from the data object

My question is: Whenever my rightDetail label has more content, I don't want to change the font or size instead I would like to extend cell size to fit content as well as my left detail to stay center aligned.

But when my rightDetail content grows, my left label is moving up instead of staying in the center.

Since the table view cell style is "Right Detail", I cannot set `constraints`

Please advice how can I set my left label to stay center

This is how my table looks when I have more content on the right detail label

[image]

Comment: You need to learn autolayout. There are plenty of tutorials for it out there.

Comment: Hi @Glenn: Since I'm using that as right detail, Xcode isn't allowing me to add constraints

Comment: I think your best option would be to create a custom cell and then add the constraints using auto layout. You could try [tableView(_:heightForRowAt:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614998-tableview) to adjust the cell height, but since you're using static cells, I think this would be too hacky - and I don't know how you could center the left label of a non-custom static cell.